# Running electron.js as a screensaver

Tags: c#, node.js, electron, heap-memory, windows-screensaver

I'm trying to create a screensaver that runs on Electron.js. I'm starting the Electron.js application through a C# console application. Everything is working great, but when the screensaver starts after the timer, all the screens turn black and all the Electron.js windows don't work.
I found out that the reason for this is that Windows screensavers only allocate a certain amount of heap memory and that it can't be changed.

Does anyone know if it is possible to allocate more memory? If not, how can I start the Electron.js application through a C# console application on the normal Desktop, so that it doesn't run out of memory?

Right now I'm starting the Electron.js process with this line:

```
process.start("path/to/screensaver/saver.exe");
```

I really hope someone can help me. I've been stuck with this issue for a while now.

Thanks in regards.

Comment: *I found out that the reason for this is that Windows screensavers only allocate a certain amount of heap memory and that it can't be changed.*... *Does anyone know if it is possible to allocate more memory?* You seem to have answered your own question? Where did you read this and what makes you think this is inaccurate?

Comment: I read it somewhere on StackOverflow, but I can't remember where. I don't say that it is inaccurate, but maybe the person who wrote the answer wasn't as smart as someone who read this question.

Comment: This sounds like this [question is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)